# How to resolve error "Input String not in correct format"

Tags: c#, asp.net

Getting error on this line in my code:-

```
 objGetAdd.UserAddlID = int.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
```

Button in aspx page:-

```
<asp:Button ID="btnEditAdd" Text="Edit" 
CausesValidation="false" CommandName="Edit" Visible="false" runat="server" OnCommand="btnEditAdd_Click" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("UserAddID") %>/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not have a `CommandArgument` specified in Button "btnEditAdd".

However, you are then trying to `int.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString())`

Most likely the  `CommandArgument` is null and hence the above line will fail.

Try adding a commandArgument="1" kind of value to your button first.

Comment: Have corrected the code..gave that 111 value for testing purpose..plz check my code now..thnx

Comment: @Serenity - `CommandArgument='<%#Eval("UserAddID")'`- Is this button inside some kind of grid? What is "UserAddID" and how are you binding this value to the command argument? can you post that code as well?

Comment: No the button is not inside of grid or anything..actually there's this list of Addresses inside a repeater ..when any address Link button is clicked then this "btnEditAdd " is rendered OUTSIDE the repeater..I am trying to edit the adressses that are inside of repeater using this "btnEditAdd"..How do u bind Command argument ? cud u plz give a link or something that shows how Command argument is bound for a control that is not inside of a repeater or grid??

Comment: @Serenity - It is most likely the <%#Eval("UserAddID") that you have used is of no use as the Eval works when binding a control to a source. You need to assign the commandArgument value to that button either in your markup or from the codebehind with whatever value you want it to have. You are currently not doing that anywhere from the code that you have shown.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: Okay, so now you've changed the code... how about doing some debugging? What's the value of `e.CommandArgument` at execution time? What does the generated HTML look like? What is `UserAddID` when *generating* the page? These are questions which are hard for us to determine, but should be debugging 101 for you.

Comment: Have corrected the code..gave that 111 value for testing purpose..plz check my code now..thnx

Comment: e.CommandArgument's value shows as empty string when debugging

Comment: @Serenity: And what does the generated HTML look like?